# Sonarlint issues shown in eclipse not in bind Sonarqube project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I installed the SonarLint 6.6 for Eclipse (neno) using Eclipse marketplace.

[image]

It successful scanned my java project and returned 4725 items found.

[image]

I bind the project to SonarQube server which installed at the same PC 
[image]

After anaylized the project again, I click "update all project bindings" at the SonarQube at Eclipse server to syn the result to SonarQube

[image]

[image]

My Questions

1) How can I syn the analyzed result to my server?

2) Are there any tool to category the analyzed result such as by severity? as I only interest on the "BUG"?

3) How can I configure the rule of SonarLint in Eclipse Environment?

May I have your help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> 1) How can I syn the analyzed result to my server?

To analyze your project and see the result on SonarQube, you need to use one of the scanners. For example, if you build your project with Maven, then you can use the [scanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven). Or if you build your project with [Ant](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant) or [Gradle](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle?src=contextnavpagetreemode), there is a dedicated scanner for those too (as I linked). If you don't use any build tool, then you can use the [scanner for CLI](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner).

> 2) Are there any tool to category the analyzed result such as by severity? as I only interest on the "BUG"?

I'm not aware of such tool. And, at the time of this writing, the **SonarLint On-The-Fly** view is not configurable to do this (unlike the "native" **Problems** view of Eclipse). (This might be a good idea for future improvement, if there's enough interest for it.)

> 3) How can I configure the rule of SonarLint in Eclipse Environment?

It seems your project is bound to a project on SonarQube.
You can configure this on SonarQube.
In SonarQube, each project is associated with a [quality profile](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles). 
After you can configure what rules to include,
you can update the bindings in Eclipse to apply the same configuration for SonarLint in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I assigned to have a blind source code quality review on a project with several thousand java programs. Sonarlint looks not a good tool for this exercise. Do you have any Eclipse plugin recommend?

Comment: @CalvinLai I'm not sure I understand. SonarLint for Eclipse is a good way to show quality issues in Eclipse. If you want to see quality issues on SonarQube, you need to use one of the SonarQube scanners, as I explained.